# VSO copy to task is failing for unknown reason

Tags: powershell, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a visual studio team services build setup. I have 2 steps so far.

Visual Studio Build - this works beautifully 
Copy files - this works depending on where I set the target path too.

Now I need the outputted files to be deployed to our application. There are multiple tasks to use: copy files, copy and publish build artifacts, publish build artifacts, etc.

I decided on copy files because it seemed the most straight forward, and after all, I just need to copy files. :)

[image]
My issue is that if I change the target folder to E:\test\ it copies everything wonderfully. However with the target folder set to the application path: E:\Program Files\App\CI I get the following error message:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Copy Files to: E:\Program Files\App\CI
******************************************************************************
Set workingFolder to default: E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9
found 65 files
shell.js: internal error
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\"E:'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:747:18)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:11:8)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3)
    at E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:63:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object._mkdir (E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:48:8)
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: CopyFiles
******************************************************************************
System.Exception: Task CopyFiles failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
Worker Worker-56b6a6c0-8c1d-4dc3-b200-385e5c7a7625 finished running job 56b6a6c0-8c1d-4dc3-b200-385e5c7a7625
```

In the error it says:

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'E:\build\agent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.9\"E:'

The trailing "E: jumps out at me, but am not sure why it's doing that. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Wrap the path in quotation marks, it could be that it's not properly handling paths with spaces.

Comment: Good call! It didn't work though.....but I ran a test and it seems that it does not like the spaces. I've tried putting & in front of it with single and double quotes and no luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I see this issue with "Copy Files" task is that I entered a redundant blank space at the begin of the Target Folder path. I just tried it again and can still get the same error with the blank space enter. So you may need to check this and then try build again.[image]

Comment: I checked this and didn't have one. It seems that it's because I have a space in my target folder path. Do you know of any way to have this escaped? I've tried every way to escape the space that I could on google and here.

Comment: Did you try putting quotes around the path?

Comment: @ChrisWhisenhunt The space in the path should not effect the feature.  I tried a path with space in the middle of the path, it works fine. Since the copy task version I use is still 1.0.5 but you are using 1.0.9, I'm not sure if it is caused by the new version as there is a new issue introduced in 1.0.9. See this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/1107. And I will try this when my task is updated to 1.0.9.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Good to know and thanks for the research on this, it's very much appreciated. I'll keep an eye on that thread. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisWhisenhunt My build agent is updated just now and the copy file task is also failed with space in the Target Folder now (Copy task version is still 1.0.5). I have helped you submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect page, refer to this link for details: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2284012. For now, you can add a powershell or batch step to copy the files you want.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Thank you.

Comment: It looks like this has now been fixed.