# TFS Build fails on a Copy Files step with the error:Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, write

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

We have a rather long build that just started failing on a copy files step. It's really weird because we have two (almost) identical copy steps. First we copy to a local share (the build server is in the middle of the country and we're in CA). The second Copy step copies to a local share (where the build server is physically located) and for some reason the copy to the local share just started failing. It usually fails on the same file but it has failed on others. Here's what the error looks like:

[image]

It's pretty hard to track down an error that starts with "Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, write". Anyone seen anything like this? There's plenty of space on the share so that's not the issue.

Thanks Patrick. Here's the output with system.debug = true. This doesn't seem to help really:
[image]

Comment: You could use `system.debug=true`  in variables of your pipeline.[Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) Kindly check if you get more detail error info for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the suggestion. I've done that and added a picture above but I don't see anything that really helps. Do you?

Comment: I used to have similar error copy file task was failing for unknown reason kind like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931831/vso-copy-to-task-is-failing-for-unknown-reason  My solution here is zipping all files and unzip again.